# How to change iCloud email

Tags: icloud

I want to delete my existing iCloud email address and replace it with a new one. My Apple ID is a hotmail address which I do not want to change. I have been getting too much rubbish on my iCloud email, so I just want to delete it and replace with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Go to appleid.apple.com and add/change your email address there. However, I think you cannot set another email address anymore as the default one, other then the @me.com and @icloud.com

Answer (score 0):

Rather than change it, you could just redirect unwanted emails to a fake address, which would then bounce.
I don't know whether this makes them eventually give up sending it, but you never see it again, it's as though it never happened.

I started getting a lot of spam from some random online dating service which I dealt with in this manner.

Start at https://www.icloud.com/#mail & from the gear icon at the bottom select Rules...

Add the spam senders & redirect to something random & unlikely to exists - unknown.user123456@icloud.com etc

[image]

Bye bye spam.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete it and replace a new one?

This page is about your question. You mail is hotmail instead of @me.com, @icloud.com or @mac.com. (Apple provides these.)

So, you can see the middle part of this article about "the third party email", using ctrl+f to search "third party". You can know how to do it.

[Change your Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667)